# SSRS Ticket Counts by Stage

Tags: reporting-services, expression, iif

I am trying to get the counts for my ticket stages with a simple percent closed and my expressions are not working correctly. 
**STAGE**
-OPEN
-IN PROGRESS
-CLOSED

I am trying to just get the counts for:
-OPEN
-IN PROGRESS

The SSRS expression i am using is:

```
=COUNT(IIF (Fields!Stage.Value="Closed",1,Nothing)), COUNT(IIF (Fields!Stage.Value="In progress",1,Nothing))
```

Lastly i am trying to get the percent closed, which includes:
-OPEN
-IN PROGRESS

The Expression i am using for this is:

```
=COUNT(IIF (Fields!Stage.Value="Closed",1,Nothing)) \ COUNT(IIF (Fields!Stage.Value="In progress",1,Nothing)), COUNT(IIF (Fields!Stage.Value="Open",1,Nothing)) \ 100
```

Any Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your count function to sum and change nothing to zero(shouldn't be strictly necessary):

```
SUM(IIF (Fields!Stage.Value="Closed",1,0))
```

Comment: Jason. it seems pretty strict. your expression did not work. the below statment does get results.              =COUNT(IIF(Fields!Stage.Value="Closed",1,Nothing))

Comment: Jason. I was able to look at the expression another way. Your suggestion did work. Thank you.

Comment: =SUM(IIF(Fields!Stage.Value="Closed",1,0)) /     (SUM(IIF(Fields!Stage.Value="Closed",1,0)) +     SUM(IIF(Fields!Stage.Value="Open",1,0)) +     SUM(IIF(Fields!Stage.Value="Open",1,0)))